# Javascript `Fetch` in React native returns unexpected Identifier when passing query to the URL String

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I am trying to consume an API created using PHP in an expo Application.
But I keep having the error `JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "top"` no matter what I've tried.

My final attempt :

```
 const data = { action: "top" };
    fetch(
      `http://.../get.php?action=${encodeURIComponent(
        data.action
      )}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I have also tried the `searchParams` approach which gave me the same result.

What I am missing here.
Thanks.

Comment: The data returned might not be valid json, try using `res.text()` and see what the output is

Comment: This may be a problem on your backend side. Frontend code seems fine so fixing any bug on the backend side will solve the issue.

Comment: Well when I tried .text() the result came in, the weird thing here is that I have fetched data from the same back-end but without queries and the data was fetched with .json() instead of .text();

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will have a look at my PHP server.